# Postgresql query with non existing dates

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that works OK but does not pick up non existing dates

```
select
    j.job_id as "Job No",
    c.business_name as "Customer",
    to_char(j.date_created, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as "Created Date",
    to_char(min(sc.start_time), 'DD/MM/YYYY') as "Schedule Start",
    to_char(max(sc.end_time), 'DD/MM/YYYY') as "Schedule End",
    to_char(j.date_due, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as "Due Date"
from sampleco_jobs j
join sampleco_customers c
on j.customer_id = c.customer_id
join sampleco_schedules sc
on j.job_id = sc.job_id
where c.customer_id = 29726
group by j.job_id, c.business_name;
```

There could be multiple schedule dates per job and the query is looking for the oldest and youngest schedule date and grouping by job_id. However some jobs are not yet started and have no existing dates in the schedules table and do not show in the result. How do I get all jobs to show in the result? Also possibly add something like "no schedule" instead of a blank  Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like you just need to do `left join` with schedule table :

```
select
    j.job_id as "Job No",
    c.business_name as "Customer",
    to_char(j.date_created, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as "Created Date",
    to_char(min(sc.start_time), 'DD/MM/YYYY') as "Schedule Start",
    to_char(max(sc.end_time), 'DD/MM/YYYY') as "Schedule End",
    to_char(j.date_due, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as "Due Date"
from sampleco_jobs j
join sampleco_customers c
on j.customer_id = c.customer_id
left join sampleco_schedules sc --< left join here
on j.job_id = sc.job_id
where c.customer_id = 29726
group by j.job_id, c.business_name;
```